How to access SparkContext, GlueContext in worker node
Here is my code :
# Sample data
data = [("system1", "file1"),
    ("system1", "file2"),
    ("system1", "file3"),
    ("system2", "file1"),
    ("system2", "file2"),
    ("system2", "file3")]

# Create RDD of Row objects
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: Row(erp_name=x[0], file_master=x[1]))

# Create DataFrame
file_column_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

args_list = [('system1', 'abc1', 'my_bucket', 'abc'), ('system2', 'def1', 'my_bucket', 'def'), ('system3', 'xyz1', 'my_bucket', 'xyz')]

def process_dq_checks(row):
    system, file_type, db_name, table_name = row
    query = f"select city from tableA where \
        lower(system_name)='{system}' and lower(file_type)='{file_type}'"
    row = read_redshift_data(glueContext, query).toDF().rdd.collect()[0]['city']
    print("row : ", row)
       
    # Script generated for node AWS Glue Data Catalog
    table = f"glue_catalog.{db_name}.{table_name}"
    
    # Read data processed today from iceberg table
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE date(updated_at) = current_date"
    df = read_athena_data(spark, query=query)
    df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "df")

args_list = sc.parallelize(args_list)
result_rdd = args_list.map(lambda x: process_dq_checks(*x))

results = result_rdd.collect()

Above code is failing with "PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063."
And If I try to create spark and gluecontext within function, then it's failing with "RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver."
How can I resolve this issues and achieve the parallelism here by distributing workload to all the worker nodes?
